# How to find rebased git commits in a freshly cloned repository?

Tags: git, rebase

I need to find all rebased commits in a git repository and it seems like `git reflog` is the way to go; however, since `git reflog` shows all refs in a local repository and mine is a freshly cloned repository the output of `git reflog` is mostly empty. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Define "rebased commits" here: rebasing simply copies commits. If you never had the originals, why do you care which ones are copies? If you *do* have the originals, are you seeking to match up "originals that you still have, that I used to have but discarded in favor of my copies"? If so, how did you get them ("them" = both the originals, and the copies)? (These are all relevant to finding an efficient answer.)

Comment: What do you mean "rebased commits"?

Comment: Rebased is probably not the right word; I am looking for squashed commits rather and rebasing seems to do a similar thing (I could be wrong). The situation is this - since squashing combines a number of commits into a single commit, if I want to look at the contents changed by a single one of those commits instead of the diff of the squashed commit I would first need to identify the squashed commit. I was looking at `git reflog` for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a git repository, it does not pull any history of commits you have rebased. The best way to see which commits you have rebased is by looking through the reflog on the repository that you rebased in.

EDIT: Based on your comment, it looks like you want a list of dangling commits that exist in the remote repo. If you just use `git clone` to pull down the repository, you will not be able to get what you are looking for. When you clone a git repo, git only copies objects that are referenced somewhere. Dangling objects are not downloaded. If you want to get a list of dangling commits, you would need to get that information from the remote repository. If your remote is Github, it is highly unlikely you will be able to get these objects at all. If it is a server you have access to, I would suggest running `git fsck` or `git reflog` on the remote server in the repo. However, I would be willing to bet that you don't have access (which I why you are cloning).

Comment: I should have been more clear; Basically, as part a project I am looking through a number of random repositories, so I haven't rebased in any commits for these repos. I am trying to extract some information from them and for that I want to be able to identify 'lost' commits such as those by squashing or rebasing. In this case, how would I identify them if 'git reflog' doesn't work with newly cloned or forked repositories?

Comment: @user97468 I updated my answer to reflect this. If you do have access to the remote repo, it would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, that's right, unfortunately.. I am basically trying to get some statistics from a number of repositories and I don't have access to any of them. I do wonder though.. what information do I have when I clone a project, such as in the object store? I understand that the 'squashed' commits no longer exist in the project history but I have been able to access them on GitHub by querying the GitHub API using the SHA of the intermediate 'squashed' commit. Does that mean they are present in the object store even if they aren't easily accessible?

Comment: The Github repository only has those intermediate commits since it had them at one point. They are still in the object store for that repo. However, when you clone, you don't pull those objects down, so it isn't possible to access those locally. The only objects you get from cloning are objects that are currently being referenced in the Github repo.

Comment: Are these squashed commits ones from Github PR squashing? If so, you _might_ be able to pull all the PRs and check if those commits are referenced anywhere else besides the PRs. This would be fairly complicated, though, and I wouldn't know where to start.